# Why is the status issue not showing?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the status issue not displaying? I am using a toggle to toggle between no issue and issue, but for some reason I can't find out why issue is not showing up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on('click', function(){
    $("#No_Issue").toggle();
    $("#Issue").toggle();
  })
})
</script>

<style>
#No_Issue{
  display: block
 }
 
#Issue{
  display: none
 }
</style>
<body>
<!-- ******************************************Refresh************************************* -->

   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60">



<!-- ******************************************BUTTON************************************* -->
    <button id="btn" type="button"value= "edit">Switch Status</button>

<p>


<!--/************************************** No Issue Style***********************************/ -->

  <div id ="No_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="No_stu" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

    </div>





<!--//**************************************Issue Style*********************************** -->
  <div id ="Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="stu" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
    
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Student Portal</font></strong></p>

      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed `<div id ="No_stu">` tag but you forgot to close `<div id ="No_Issue">` tag that is why HTML parser treated your `<div id="Issue">` node as a child of `<div id ="No_Issue">` and it was hidden with its parent on toggling.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on('click', function(){
    $("#No_Issue").toggle();
    $("#Issue").toggle();
  })
})
</script>

<style>
#No_Issue{
  display: block
 }
 
#Issue{
  display: none
 }
</style>
<body>
<!-- ******************************************Refresh************************************* -->

   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60">



<!-- ******************************************BUTTON************************************* -->
    <button id="btn" type="button"value= "edit">Switch Status</button>

<p>


<!--/************************************** No Issue Style***********************************/ -->

  <div id ="No_Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="No_stu" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

    </div>
</div>





<!--//**************************************Issue Style*********************************** -->
  <div id ="Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">


    <div id="stu" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
    
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-
                bottom:10px;"><strong><font size="6">Student Portal</font></strong></p>

      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```